# How to serve up Python logging file with heroku?

Tags: python, logging, heroku, flask

So, I have a simple web-app running on Heroku, which provides a nice front-end for inputting some data and running a particular calculation (it's an academic thing). Throughout, I use python's `logging` library a lot, since there are a lot of steps to the computation and I want to make sure they're all right.

But recently, the person I'm doing this with decided they want to see the logs too, which should have been easy -- I just send them all into a `.log` file with a `FileHandler`, so I'll just serve up the file? But, no, that doesn't work with Heroku.

Alright, well, maybe I'll try using a `QueueHandler`, and then dumping the queue into the cache (I'm using a memcached service), so as to grab it when the user requests the logs?

```
log = logging.getLogger("mc")
logqueue = queue.Queue()
queue_handler = QueueHandler(logqueue)
log.handlers = [ queue_handler ]

...(computation, generates logs)

cache.set('logList', logqueue.queue)
```

Again this works on my local but not on Heroku; at the `cache.set` line the logqueue says that it's empty.

All of these things work on my local machine, and I'm tearing my hair out here trying to figure out why none work on Heroku. Does anyone here have any ideas on what to try from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to figure it out -- unsurprisingly I was just being stupid! Or at least, I was missing something important:

At some point early in the code, I'd needed to set `log.setLevel(level = logging.INFO)`, since all my logs were of the `INFO` type. But, I'd done that in `manage.py`, which would *normally* be totally fine except for the fact that in this particular case I set this app up as a Blueprint and register it as a sub-URL, using a *different* `manage.py`, a higher-level one that controls everything. The net effect was that my line

```
log.setLevel(level = logging.INFO)
```

was skipped, along with everything else in the original `manage.py`, when I tried to run it on Heroku, which used the "master" `manage.py`. And thus, my log existed, but the log level wasn't set right so it took down no logs at all.

Hope this made sense, what a headache